# Windows batch file do to conditional rename

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename

I have several hundred files named in a specific manner that need to be renamed by replacing the 13-15th character depending on what the 6th character is. I've been unable to create something that will read the 6th character but leave it alone and change only the 13-15th characters.

The files are in the format below.

```
2016-A124578_XYZ_moretext.ext
2016-B345654_XYZ_morerandomtext.ext
2016-B235689_XYZ_moredifferenttext.ext
2016-A789945_XYZ_moretext.ext
2016-C547821_XYZ_moretext.ext
```

The script needs to read the 6th character (A, B or C) and replace the *XYZ* with *AAA* or *BBB* or *CCC* depending upon the letter. The rest of the file name needs to appear the same.

```
2016-A124578_XYZ_moretext.ext becomes 2016-A124578_AAA_moretext.ext
2016-B345654_XYZ_morerandomtext.ext becomes 2016-B345654_BBB_morerandomtext.ext
```

Is it possible to make this kind of script? Would RegEx be the best way to attempt it?

Comment: If you don't already know how to write batch files, do yourself a favour and learn powershell instead. Doing anything even slightly complicated in batch is *painful*. The sooner everyone forgets it exists, the better. Powershell is so much better, and it's preinstalled on modern Windows systems. It also actually supports regex - batch doesn't.

Comment: PowerShell is unnecessarily verbose and isn't even enabled by default. Unless you have a typing fetish, stick with batch.

Comment: It's not the best language out there, but if you're trying to write actual programs without installing something new, it's Powershell or batch. Batch is a terrible pile of backwards-compatible hack on top of hack and the syntax reflects that. Powershell is verbose sometimes, but there are plenty of IDEs for it with autocompletion. Batch is fine for simple lists of commands. Anything more complicated and it's just awful. In my opinion.

Comment: @SomethingDark Worse than *unnecessarily verbose* is that it can be reduced to stupidly sparse via aliases.

Comment: @Blorgbeard In windows there is batch (and 32 bit windows also does Dos 5.5 batch), vbscript, jscript, powershell, VB.NET (6 versions from 1.0.3705 to 4.0.30319), C# (also same 6 versions), and the JScript.NET compiler. You'll find the compilers here C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 - CSC.exe, VBC.exe, and JSC.exe.

Comment: @Noodles hooray, plenty of alternatives to batch then. Although you'd still need a wrapper around some of those to compile/execute them.

Answer (score 1):

```
Set Str=2016-B345654_XYZ_morerandomtext.ext
Echo %str% %str:~0,13% %str:~5,1%%str:~5,1%%str:~5,1% %str:~16%
```

I've put spaces in it to show what part does what, remove them.

See `set /?` for help.

Answer (score 1):

I found a far more simple way to achieve this knowing the format of the files would always be as I specified above.

Simply used this in a batch file...

```
REN 2016-A*.ext 2016-A??????_AAA_*.ext
REN 2016-B*.ext 2016-B??????_BBB_*.ext
REN 2016-C*.ext 2016-C??????_CCC_*.ext
```

Comment: +1, but I can simplify this even further. Also, there are ways to make fewer assumptions that still fairly simple.. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38690293/1012053).

Answer (score 0):

even simpler :-)

```
for %A in (A B C) @do ren 2016-%A*.ext *_%A%A%A*
```

If run from a batch file, then double the percents:

```
@for %%A in (A B C) @do ren 2016-%%A*.ext *_%%A%%A%%A*
```

See [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/questions/475874/how-does-the-windows-rename-command-interpret-wildcards/475875#475875) for info on why this RENAME works.

However, the code assumes that all files within the folder follow the pattern. What if there are files that do not match the pattern that should not be renamed? The simplistic filter runs the risk of renaming files that should not be renamed.

You could be somewhat more precise with the source mask:

```
for %A in (A B C) @do ren 2016-%A??????_XYZ_*.ext *_%A%A%A*
```

But there are still two potential problems:

- `?` matches 0 or 1 character, so it guarantees there will not be more than 6 chars, but there could be fewer than 6
- `?` matches any character, not just digits.

You could use DIR /B coupled with FINDSTR to be very specific:

```
for %A in (A B C) @do for %F in (dir /b /a-d 2016-%A*.ext^|findstr /ric:"2016-%A[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_XYZ_*\.ext"') do ren "%F" *_%A%A%A*
```

But there is another solution that is both simple and precise - [a regular expression rename utility called JREN.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6081). It is pure script (hybrid batch/JScript) that runs natively on any Windows machine without the need of any 3rd party exe files.

```
jren "^(2016-([ABC])\d{6}_)XYZ(_.*\.ext)$" "$1$2$2$2$3" /i
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is a bit more verbose but I find it easier to read and modify:

```
@Echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%f in ('dir *.ext /b') do (
  set fName=%%f
  set fTag=!fName:~5,1!
  set fPrefix=!fName:~0,13!
  set fSuffix=!fName:~16!
  set fReplace=!fName:~13,3!
  if /i "!fTag!" EQU "A" set fReplace=AAA
  if /i "!fTag!" EQU "B" set fReplace=BBB
  if /i "!fTag!" EQU "C" set fReplace=CCC

  ren !fName! !fPrefix!!fReplace!!fSuffix!
)
```